# Why are anonymous, self-executing function used instead of just writing the commands

Tags: javascript, coding-style, standards

I have searched similar questions on this site but they dont answer my particular query.
Hey, so I was wondering why would you use:
 
`(function(){a+b;})();`
instead of:
`a+b;`
Its a thing I see used often in this tutorial I'm following:
[Link](http://www.somethinghitme.com/2013/01/09/creating-a-canvas-platformer-tutorial-part-one/<br)

Edit:
"*real* code for better context":
`(function() {var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();`

Edit:
Didn't know it was called IIFE, thank you for the links.

Comment: There's a good explanation for using that construct, but your sample code doesn't seem to benefit from it. Can you post *real code* for better context?

Comment: Your particular use case not covered by other answers seems fairly non-specific...

Comment: Meanwhile, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Comment: See the explanation to Immediately Invoked Function Expression, [IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for encapsulation.For not to be visible in outer scope.